# Upgrade R in Mac OS

Tags: r, macos

I'd like to upgrade R version in OS X (mountain lion).

Can I download `R-3.2.1-snowleopard.pkg` from the [CRAN site](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) and execute it to upgrade R? Do I need to delete older version before executing the pkg file?

My R version is 3.0.1 and R executable is inside `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework`.

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    47B  9 14  2013 /usr/bin/R@ -> /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/R
```

The reason why I need to upgrade R is the error on loading the 'tcltk' package. Some post on a QA site said upgrading R will resolve the issue.

```
> require(tcltk)
Loading required package: tcltk
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'tcltk', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so, 10): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libtcl8.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.0/Resources/library/tcltk/libs/tcltk.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Just download and installing should work. Give it a try.

Comment: R officially no longer supports OSX pre-mavericks. Installers and CRAN packages are no longer updated.